# Does proprietary drivers affect battery drain?

Tags: linux, amd, proprietary-drivers, amd-graphics, open-source

In Linux do proprietary drivers from people like AMD affect battery life in any way? I want to run Linux on a laptop that has an amd apu on it, but I am a bit worried about the impact.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could affect power usage, but AFAIK it is not the case.

If you have doubts, you can do some tests, or just use the open source drivers. If you are not concerned on extreme performance, the open source drivers are better because more integrated with the kernel.